# Mismatch in count even with FieldValue.increment

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My use case is that I want to keep aggregating my firebase user count in the database for quick and easy access. For that, I have a cloud function listening on `user.onCreate` and it simply increments a field in a document using the atomic `FieldValue.increment`.

Here is the code:

```
exports.createProfile = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async user => {
 return Promise.all([
    addProfileToDatabase(),
    function() {
     db.collection('someCollection').doc(docId).update({
      count: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
     )}
    }
  ])
})
```

Issue: the count in the database becomes more than the number of authenticated users shown in the **Authentication** tab of Firebase. I regularly reset it to the correct number and then it slowly increases again.

I have read about the write throttling on a document, but that should instead result in lower count if at all. But why is that the count in the database always overshoots the actual count?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, the only thing I can imagine is that your function isn't idempotent.  It's possible that functions may be invoked more than once per triggering event.  This would be an explanation why your count exceeds the expectation.

Read more about Cloud Functions idempotency in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries) and also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pwsy8XR7HNE).

Comment: Hi Doug. I have added updated the question with my code. Can `user.onCreate` trigger more than once per user?

Comment: Yes, because non-http function can be triggered more than once per event.  It's rare, but it can happen.